# How do I use my own blending formula in SVG?

Tags: svg, alphablending, blending, svg-filters

I'm using SVG.

The standard blend modes: screen, lighten, overlay, difference.  etc......   are not what I need.

I've designed a formula for another blend mode i need to use that isn't any of the standard ones, but don't know how to implement it into my SVG file so that it works.

Do I just do for example do feBlend mode="Cm = B(Cb, Cs)" within a filter?

Specifically, I want to apply the luminosity of the layer above to the alpha channel of the layer below.

There must be a way.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot provide a custom blending formula in SVG 1.1 - you are stuck with the built-ins. However, you can create other types of blending using compound filters with multiple feBlends & feComposite arithmetic mode in combination with feColorMatrix's.

Update:

What you want to do is not possible the way you want to do it. The result of an feBlend operation where one of the inputs is fully opaque is a fully opaque result. feBlend uses pre-multiplied values for its color calculations. So, you can't directly take the alpha channel of one image, and transfer it to another image's alpha channel. However, if you're trying to blend an image with its background and that's why you're trying to adjust the alpha channel, you could achieve the effect you're looking for by using the Background image as part of the blend filter (but this is only possible in IE10 and Opera today).

There is a [proposed new blend mode in the combined CSS/SVG blending spec "mode=Luminosity"](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/FXTF/rawfile/tip/compositing/index.html#blendingluminosity) which would do what you want - but that is not going to show up in browsers for a while.

Comment: Well, to be honest I'm just trying to get the luminosity of one layer to be put into the alpha channel of another.  However, feColorMatrix type="Luminance" doesn't work whatsoever.  All it does is get rid of my background image and make my source greyscale. This is most certainly not what it says on the tin.

Comment: Do you know of "Luma Track Matte". It's used for animation, but I only need it for a still image.  It does what "luminance" is supposed to do, which is apply the luminosity of the layer above to the alpha channel of the layer below.

Comment: OK.  Thanks for this script. This is the right idea.  However, you know the 'lightning' picture you used.  Well, for what I'm wanting to use it for, that 'lightning picture' is'nt greyscale.  It's a colourful photo.  Plus, I need it not to get darker from the mask.

Comment: And there's a complication which is that I'm actually wanting it to be inverted. So instead of 'the lighter it gets the more transparent it gets'  I need 'the darker it gets the more transparent it gets'.

Comment: OK, I'm going to be straight with you and say that I already knew how to blend images together. I'm wanting a luma-mask.  Unless I am very mistaken, 'Multiply' doesn't achieve this; it darkens the image, and that isn't what I want.   An inverted Luma-matte (mask) fills in the bits that are darker with the exact colour underneath.   No existing blend mode does this.

Comment: Is there any way of viewing its result (other than browers)?

Comment: Sorry if I'm not understanding, but it's just a specification - a document right now. It's not implemented in code yet, so you can't see it in action anywhere.

Comment: But lastly, is there any way of using Masks in svg to achieve the luma-mask (luma-matte)?